# Upper and lower limits

Tags: real-analysis

Find the following limits:

(1) $\limsup_{n\to\infty } \sin (n!) $

(2) $\liminf_{n\to\infty } \sin (n!) $

(3) $\limsup_{n\to\infty } \cos (n!) $

(4) $\liminf_{n\to\infty } \cos (n!) .$

Comment: MO is for questions of math research.

Comment: This is an interesting question because it looks less hopeless than many other seemingly similar questions. This one provides a chance for solving it.

Comment: I'd simply ask about the behavior of $\ \exp(i\!\cdot\! n!)$

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that the lim infs are $-1$ and the lim sups are $+1$, but I think this requires better information about rational approximations of $\pi$ than we
have available.  What I can say, though, is that 
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin(n! \pi e) = 0$, while $\lim_{n \to \infty} \cos((2n)! \pi e) = -1$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \cos((2n+1)! \pi e) = +1$.

Now we strongly suspect, but haven't been able to prove, that $\pi e$ is irrational.  If by some miracle it happens to be rational, then the limit points of $\exp(n! i)$ as $n \to \infty$ are a finite set of roots of unity.